# python fuzz clusters with labels

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

[image]

wondering if anyone knows how to go about doing this in python.

Is there a way to fuzzy match the first column(Fruit) against itself and build an output column like the 2nd column(Cluster)?

thank you!

Comment: Huge number of ways to go about this. e.g. [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is number of single-character changes needed to make one string into another string. Or there are [semantic similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979970/how-to-use-word2vec-to-calculate-the-similarity-distance-by-giving-2-words) methods, which care about meaning and not letters. Before you can do this you need to decide what "similar" means.

Comment: I would say the first.